# How to do tomography reconstruction if I don't know the order of the projections

Tags: 3d, tomography-reconstruction

If I got several projections and don't know the angles related to each. How could I reconstruct an Image (3D Volume)

Comment: You can't. Tomography is an ill-posed problem, and one of the properties of that is that tiny perturbation on the input (geometry, projections) can create large perturbations on the output (volume). People calibrate their scanners with lasers to know distances in the micrometer level, so not knowing the angles will totally screw any possibility of recon.